# Reading oracle row into a object Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, asp.net-core

I'm trying to read from an Oracle database in Asp.net, but the table has a big amount of rows.
All the examples I've seen online read from each column separately instead of just reading the whole row into an object.
Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "read from each column separately instead of just reading the whole row into an object", everything does that on some level, no matter the database, because the results have to be processed. It sounds like you want an abstraction layer like an Entity Framework, with a Provider for Oracle, and there is one.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Can you please elaborate or provide a link for a specific tutorial? because I can't seem to find what you're stating. I'm coming from spring and postgres, there I would create a model class and all the fields would automatically be set. Is there anything like that in c# and Oracle?

Comment: Here's a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your query and concatenate all the rows into 1, not ideal but it would get you what you are looking for.  Below is example of concatenating 3 columns into 1, comma separated.

```
 select col1 || ',' || col2 || ',' || col3 combinedCol
```